# Is using the same name for LINQ Queries range and iteration variables good practise?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

At “[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause)” it says “The range variable is like an iteration variable in a foreach statement except for one very important difference: a range variable never actually stores data from the source. It's just a syntactic convenience that enables the query to describe what will occur when the query is executed."

The example at [Introduction to LINQ Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) (C#)” below is one of the few where the range and iteration variables have the same name (“num”)

```
// 2. Query creation.
var numQuery =
    from num in numbers
    where (num % 2) == 0
    select num;

// 3. Query execution.
foreach (int num in numQuery)
{
    Console.Write("{0,1} ", num);
}
```

Usually MSDN examples assign the range and iteration variables different names.

Are there any reasons not to use the same name for both the range variable and iteration variable when it seems convenient to do so?

Comment: This is all just fashion sense, and its so subjective that any answer would be futile. However because these are even numbers, i my self would call it, `evenNumbers` and on that note, ill quickly exit this conversation

Comment: @TheGeneral ...you'll exist this conversation? Sounds like magic :D

Comment: @John yeah hahah, fixerated

Comment: Thanks for your answer General - I just wanted to make that there were no hidden gotchas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the step 2 you're building a query and at the 3 step you've already executed the query, 
so the (1st)num var didn't exist at the same time to the (foreach)num var

technically both num var represent the same concept, so you can use as you want.
Generally devs user 'item' for range variable

if the foreach statement is long and complicated, i use your naming convention 
...otherwise => 'item'